# Can ZipList be Distributive?

Tags: haskell, applicative, traversable, distributive

Base provides [ZipList](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList), which is just a wrapper for `[]` where `<*>` is based on `zip` instead of cartesian-product. This isn't the default because it's not consistent with the `Monad []` instance, but some people find it more intuitive, and both behaviors are useful in different contexts.

Edward Kmett provides [Distributive](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Distributive.html), the dual of `Traversable`. A Traversable can be mapped/pushed/distributed into any Applicative Functor; a Distributive can be pulled/factored out of any Functor. (For reasons I haven't unpacked, `distribute` does not require the outer layer to be Applicative.)

[Length-indexed lists are Distributive](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vec-0.4/docs/Data-Vec-Lazy.html#t:Vec), and work how you'd expect. Specifically, their Applicative instance is based on `zip`, *just like `ZipList`*! This suggests `ZipList` could also be `Distributive`, which would be useful.

The docs for `Distributive` note two things that must be true of any instance:

- *"It [must be] isomorphic to `(->) x` for some `x`."*

  - A list is isomorphic to a *partial* function `Int ->`.
- *"[It] will need to have a way to consistently zip a potentially infinite number of copies of itself."*

  - This is more-or-less the *raison d'être* of `ZipList`.

Is that good enough? I spent a couple hours this afternoon trying to write `instance Distributive ZipList where distributive = ...` and couldn't quite get it to work. For *most* functors `f ZipList a` there's an obvious meaning to `distribute f`, although I worry that might just be because I'm not thinking of enough *non*-Traversable functors.

- `Maybe` is tricky; should `distribute Nothing` be `[]` or `repeat Nothing`? But `distribute` is dual to `sequenceA`, and the `Traversable Maybe` instance says it should be `repeat Nothing`.
- `(->) e` might be the dealbreaker.

  - Intuitively `distribute $ const (repeat x) = repeat (const x)`.
  - We can extend that to any function that's guaranteed to return an infinite list; it looks kinda like `(\i -> (! i) <$> f) <$> [0..]`.
  - We can extend *that* to functions returning finite lists; we end up with an infinite list of *partial* functions. It's not obvious to me that that's unacceptable; partial functions show up all the time when working with lists.
  - But that means `distribute $ const [] ≅ repeat undefined`, which is kinda silly.
  - The instance `Applicative ZipList` contains an important design decision: `length (a <*> b) == min (length a) (length b)` (as opposed to an error or whatever). We're not leveraging that at all; the way I can see we might would be `distribute = const []`.

Does anyone see a way forward?

If the partial-function interpretation were "acceptable", could we generalize that in any less-dumb way than `distribute f = (\i -> (!! i) <$> f) <$> [0..]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it cannot be distributive.

The obvious `Distributive` instance for [`Pair`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-8.10.2/docs/Pair.html#t:Pair) looks like this:

```
instance Distributive Pair where
    distribute vs = Pair (pFst <$> vs) (pSnd <$> vs)
```

Now let's think about the list instance. (Let's ignore the `ZipList` noise for now and just suppose basic lists have the zippy instance.) We require `distribute . distribute = id`. Suppose

```
x = distribute (Pair "" "a")
```

so that the law requires:

```
distribute x = Pair "" "a"
```

We can substitute the definition of `distribute` for `Pair`, and get:

```
Pair (pFst <$> x) (pSnd <$> x) = Pair "" "a"
```

This is a problem, because list's `(<$>)` preserves length, and here we are requiring it to return answers of two different lengths when provided with the same argument. Whoops!

As an alternative, you might be interested in `data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)`, the type of guaranteed-infinite lists, which *can* be made `Distributive`:

```
sHead :: Stream a -> a
sHead (Cons a _) = a

sTail :: Stream a -> Stream a
sTail (Cons _ as) = as

instance Distributive Stream where
    distribute streams = Cons (sHead <$> streams) (distribute (sTail <$> streams))
```

Comment: `distribute . distribute = id` certainly shuts this down, and I see it is _briefly_ mentioned in the docs; Thanks!

Comment: Typeclass should really list counterexamples (like [Phil Freeman's Counterexamples of Type Classes](https://blog.functorial.com/posts/2015-12-06-Counterexamples.html)) in their docs as they can be the most helpful in shaping an intuition, `Distributive ZipList` would be a great one to add although Edward Kmett is punting on releasing a new version that completely changes `Distributive`